# Insight on and How to Work Around a (allegedly) Windows Focus Bug

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, focus, qt5

So let me give a bit of back story on this as well as explain what the Windows focus bug is since I can't find anything about it online.

I'm making an app that asks the user to log into his account when the app starts. A bug was found that if the user were to launch the app and immediately click on something else while the app was loading, our app would have a blinking cursor in the Line Edit box, as though it had keyboard focus. However, when he would type, nothing would go into the box!

I can see the frustration that would ensue, so I've spent the better part of the last few days investigating this issue. What I have found is that the way Qt5 handles windows messages, looks fine to me.. The only way this bug can be reproduced, is if the user launches our app, and then withing a couple hundredths of a second (maybe more on a slow computer), clicks to focus something else.

This told me that the bug might not have anything to do with our app. How can our app handle a WM_KILLFOCUS message if it hasn't even started yet? So I thought hmm.. could it be a Windows thing?

Sure enough, I was able to reproduce this bug 100% of the time with Microsoft Word, Notepad, Notepad++, and SublimeText3 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8. That being said, it seems like this is something that Windows fails to handle properly. I cannot find anything about this bug online (its particularly difficult to word in a phrase). Has anybody seen this before? What did you do to work around it?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly obtaining input focus after the application starts?

Comment: @Captain: The restrictions for calling [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) are fairly prohibitive. If the process at the time of call is elevated, it is basically Game Over.

Comment: Why not just call `GetActiveWindow`, and if it returns `NULL`, then your application isn't active, so don't display the cursor. Also, you can't really call it _the_ Windows Focus Bug if you can't find anything about it online. That would imply it's a well-known thing.

Comment: Also, if you look at the guidance on [using caret's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), they have an example where the caret is created in `WM_SETFOCUS` and destroyed in `WM_KILLFOCUS`. I guess many applications (yes, even MS ones) won't follow that approach, and will instead create the caret on initialisation.

Comment: Checking GetActiveWindow will not work. GetActiveWindow only returns the active window on the thread that it was called on. It does not necessarily mean there are not active windows in other threads. At least, if I am understanding this article correctly:

http://chabster.blogspot.com/2010/03/focus-and-window-activation-in-win32.html

Though I have tried to see what returns when it is called, and it will always return Null on startup. Since the app was just started, and this is the first call to focus, no other window has been active on this thread, it returns null, which doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Likewise, as IInspectable has said, SetForegroundWindow is pretty restrictive. Qt5 has a requestActivateWindow() function that only calls SetForegroundWindow and SetFocus. I'm going to look at the link icabod suggested, but aside from that the only think I can think to do is to check every current windows process for keyboard focus, and if a separate process has it, then force a WM_KILLFOCUS message on my app.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/16/10456992.aspx for a description of how this happens.  I *think* that you can prevent it in your application by checking whether GetForegroundWindow returns your window or not.

Comment: @Harry Calling `GetForegroundWindow` will not prevent anything, and there is nothing you can do with the return value to change things. The Edit control displays a caret on activation, and the window is active, albeit not the foreground window. Qt5 makes matters worse, if anything: Now you have to deal with two sets of rules that hardly ever agree.

Comment: @IInspectable: it seems to me that it should be possible to use GetForegroundWindow to determine whether your application is in the foreground or not, and deactivate your main window if you aren't.  Is there a problem with this approach that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Harry Checking whether the foreground window and the active window are different is the easy part. Identifying the correct time when to perform the check is harder. I don't know of a way to deactivate a window, if the application is not in the foreground, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: there might be some trial and error involved in getting it working, but my guess is that you can check when the main window first receives WM_ACTIVATE or shortly afterwards.  If you can't prevent the window from activating, you could instead use SetFocus to move the focus to a dummy control.

Comment: It also complicates things when debugging because if you are stepping through the code to see what is currently the foreground window, it will always be the cpp file you are debugging. In order to see what is really going on I have been using API Monitor, a program that inspects and logs all windows level messages, where they go, where they come from, what the parameters were, etc. Its pretty impressive. Still, this problem is a complicated one.

I am glad that it isn't just me and this isn't some silly cut and dry thing I overlooked. It looks like most programs overlook this issue.

Comment: There is only ever one foreground window, there may be multiple active windows, and there is also a keyboard focus window. It seems like in the Windows API that these things may have overlapping responsibilities that cannot be exposed without actually seeing Windows source. Unfortunately, given the fact that I haven't seen an example of a program that handles this edge case, I'm not sure it is worth the hours of development time to fix. I think ever suggestion I have seen here is something I have looked at myself haha. Thank you guys for discussing it with me!

Comment: Also, @Harry, Sure I could force focus to mitigate this issue, but that presents an even worse and more noticeable problem! I don't ever want my app to steal focus from whatever the user is doing. I just want it to understand when something else has focus so that the cursor in the edit box doesn't blink as though it does have focus. I imagine this is something Microsoft has overlooked in their API.

Comment: Here is my theory on how this problem occurs. You click your icon to start Microsoft Word, immediately you click somewhere else, SetFocus() gets invoked and a WM_SETFOCUS message gets sent to whatever you clicked on, and a WM_KILLFOCUS gets sent to.. nothing, because a handle for Microsoft Word has not yet been created and Windows has not yet recognized it as something that can have focus. So given the nature of the API, how could you possibly fix that? My guess is, you cannot. All you can do is some hacky workaround. Thoughts?

Comment: I was under the impression that SetFocus only affected the local focus and wouldn't result in your app stealing focus.  Looking at the documentation again I'm not sure that's true.  It would probably be better to prevent the WM_SETFOCUS from reaching the edit control in the first place, e.g., by making another control the default, and overriding that if and only if you're in the foreground.

Comment: The cause of the issue is discussed in Raymond Chen's blog post (and in the comments); Windows has to lie to your application about being active to ensure backwards compatibility.  However, I quite agree that this isn't worth spending much time on, at least from a commercial perspective.